# How to parse a single row from a CSV file for each java run and for the next run parse the next row?

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, key

I'm a beginner to java and I have a java class that reads in data from a CSV file which looks like this:

BUS|ID|Load|Max_Power

1  |   2 |  1   |     10.9

2  |    3 |  2   |    8.0

My problem is this: I have to consider for each java run (program execution), only 1 row at a time. For example for my first run I need to read in only the first row and then for my second run I need to read in the data from the second row. 
Would using Hashmaps be the right way to search for the keys for each run?

Comment: pls define what do they mean: `each java run` `first run` and `second run`? If you meant 3 different java processes, you have to somehow persist the state (last read no, header stuff) in file or database.

Comment: I generally mean the program execution, each time it is executed I want only one row to be read in at a time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your program has to "remember" something beyond it's termination, you need to store this information somewhere (file, registry, ...).

**Step 1** Figure out how to do file I/O (read/write files) with java. You need this to store your information, the line number in this case).

**Step 2** Implement the logic:

- read `lineToRead` from memory file (e.g. `1`)
- read line `lineToRead` (`1`) from data file and parse the data (take a look at [@Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent)s answer for a nice explanation how to do so)
- increment `lineToRead` (`1 -> 2`) and save it in to the memory file.

**Hint:** When mulitple instances of your program are going to run in parallel, you have to ensure the mutual exclusion / make the whole process (read, increment, write) atomic to prevent the *lost update effect*.

Comment: Thanks, I understood how the whole process could work. But I din't clearly understand step 1, can you give me an example?

Comment: @neo-su I can't give an example because the step is about figuring out / learning how to do file I/O with java. I can only give an example implementation if you want to, but that will not be much of a learning effect for you.

Comment: Ok, I see you mean something like Scanner or something. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you read the 1st line (the header), you split by `|` got string array (`headerArray`). Then init a hashmap  `<String, List<String>>` (or `Multimap` if you use guava or other api) with elements in your string array as key.

Then you read each data row, split by `|`, again you got string array(`dataArray`), you just get the map value by: `map.get(headerArray[index of dataArray])`. Once you locate the map entry/value, you can do following logic (add to the list).

You can also design a `ValueObjectType` type with those attributes, and a special setter accepting `int index, String value`, there you check which attribute the value should go. In this way, you don't need map any longer, you need a `List<ValueObjectType>`

Comment: Nice explanation, but that was not asked for. OP asked for how to read only the 1st (data) row on the 1st program execution, only the 2nd (data) row on the 2nd program execution... only the n-th (data) row at the n-th program execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  com.csvreader.CsvReader class (available in javacsv.jar)
This class provides functionality to read CSV file row by row  .
This will serve your purpose .

here is the sample code :-

```
    CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(FileName);
      csv.readHeaders(); // headers
        while (products.readRecord()) {

            String cal = csv.get(0);
        }
```